# "Focused on target" vs "focused on the target"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence, sentence-patterns

If a light source is required to be focused on a target.

Then which one is better to write

the method requires the light source to be focused **on target**

Or

the method requires the light source to be focused on **the target**

Thank you

Comment: *On **the** target* is correct.

Comment: For example, check out second general rule here: https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/.

Answer (score 2):

Based on how definite articles work in English, if you're saying the light is focused on "the" target, you've got a specific target in mind (in the context of focusing a light fixture, that probably means something you could point to in person, for example). So that seems like what you're after here.

I understand "on target" to be a colloquial expression, so in your example that's like saying it's focused pointed purposefully or intentionally, or it's "on point" (in the colloquial use of the phrase "on point").

Comment: by using 'the target' arent we locking it to one particular target because the target objects can change??